# Can't connect Docker PostGIS container to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, localhost

I recently started experimenting with Docker and PostGIS following [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/) documentation. I have a locally installed version of QGIS which I am attempting to connect the default Postgres database to. Unfortunately I have not been able to achieve a successful connection?

Here is what I am attempting to connect with:

[image]
(https://imgur.com/a/lebIT)

I have attempted both localhost and my Docker container's IP address, as well as multiple iterations of Postgres, root, and the `'mysecretpassword'` login provided in the Docker documentation but still no luck.

The only other bit of pertinent info I can think of is the fact that I am running all this on a `Windows 7 / Ubuntu dual boot` and I have an installation of `postgresql/postgis/pgadmin` on my Windows partition as well as a postgresql folder in my `/var/lib/` directory on Ubuntu which (I think?) is from a previous installation that I removed.

Comment: What is the configuration of the pg_hba.conf ? There is set which ip-range is allowed to access the database. Also i would check the usual connectivity problems starting with ping to the docker container and a check of iptable rules.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I cannot seem to find a pg_hba.conf file. My postgresql directory only contains a main directory with no such files. I will google the ping and iptable solutions.

Comment: Hi, I found the conf file and added the ip4 and ip6 values I received from running ifconfig -a. Unfortunately I still cannot seem to connect.